# setLeftTitle in Silverstripe 3.1

Tags: silverstripe, form-fields

I have just jumped up the Silverstripe bandwagon.
I have been trying to get the following effect of static text in front of a text field on the `getCMSfields` form:

```
Telephone number:   +36 [__________]
```

where "telephone number:" is obviously the field title (which can be altered via `->setTitle()` and `+36` is a static prefix prepended to the left of the input field.

I have been trying with `->setLeftTitle('+36')` but it does not seem to have any effect.

BTW. `->setRightTitle('something')` - which I expected to append a label to the right of input field, works identically to `->setDescription()`.

I'm confused. So is there any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [FieldGroup class](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-FieldGroup.html)

```
public function getCMSFields($fields) {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields($fields);

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main',
        FieldGroup::create(
            new HeaderField('+36'),
            new TextField('PhoneNumber','')
        )->setTitle('Telephone number')
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Personally I'd use two TextFields for cosmetic reasons, and enforce some validation on the TelephonePrefix.

Comment: I replaced HeaderField with a LabelField, but despite that the label needs proper CSS alignment.

Comment: You could start tweaking individual fields with Javascript/JQuery, but be mindful of how it affects other parts of the CMS.

I haven't tested any of this but it should put you on the right path. Make a file "somefile.js" and save it in mysite/javascript. In getCMSFields:

`public function getCMSFields(){Requirements::javascript("mysite/javascript/somefile.js");}
`

Then in your javascript, something like:

`$(function) { $("#some.selector").css({'attribute', 'value'})}`

Sorry for all the edits, couldn't figure out comment markup

Comment: Appreciated! The docs seems so terse that I gladly read every snippet.

Answer (score 2):

The default template does not render the left title. To do this, you will probably need to create a custom form field template (called `FormFieldLeftTitle.ss`) or something, and include `$LeftTitle` in the appropriate spot:

```
<div id="$Name" class="field<% if $extraClass %> $extraClass<% end_if %>">
    <% if $Title %><label class="left" for="$ID">$Title</label><% end_if %>
    <div class="middleColumn">
        $LeftTitle
        $Field
    </div>
    <% if $RightTitle %><label class="right" for="$ID">$RightTitle</label><% end_if %>
    <% if $Message %><span class="message $MessageType">$Message</span><% end_if %>
    <% if $Description %><span class="description">$Description</span><% end_if %>
</div>
```

You can then call `$myFormField->setTemplate('FormFieldLeftTitle')` to use this template.